# How to open a stream of multiple images in Microsoft Photo UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp

I was wondering about a curious detail I noticed: when I open a StorageFile that is an image...

```
Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(StorageFile image);
```

...it opens ONLY that image.

If I, instead, double-click on an image, it opens all the images, allowing the user to navigate through them with virtual or key arrows.

Do you know how to do it by coding?

Thank everyone for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is provided by the OS and you can implement similar functionality in your app.

When your app has a file type association and you open a file in a folder which also has neighboring files of type your app can handle, you will get a reference to those files as well as part of he activation.

The [`FileActivatedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.fileactivatedeventargs) implement the [`IFileActivatedEventArgsWithNeighboringFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.ifileactivatedeventargswithneighboringfiles.neighboringfilesquery#Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_IFileActivatedEventArgsWithNeighboringFiles_NeighboringFilesQuery) interface. This interface has a [`NeighboringFilesQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.ifileactivatedeventargswithneighboringfiles.neighboringfilesquery#Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_IFileActivatedEventArgsWithNeighboringFiles_NeighboringFilesQuery) property which is a normal UWP [storage file query result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.search.storagefilequeryresult) which you can use to retrieve the neighboring files. In `App.xaml.cs` override the `OnFileActivated` method to get access to the `FileActivatedEventArgs` and the forementioned `NeighboringFilesQuery` property.